# Sencha Touch - How to change sdk path

Tags: extjs, sencha-touch, sencha-touch-2

After creating a projects with Sencha Touch SDK folder as the parent the projects inside of it, I want to change the separate projects each one having it own touch folder, like illustrated bellow :

Before :

```
touch-sdk/
    project1/
    project2/
    project3/
    ...
```

After :

```
project1/
    touch-sdk/
    ...

project2/
    touch-sdk/
    ...

project3/
    touch-sdk/
    ...
```

What should I change to make this happen ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might want to take a look at Sencha Touch Workspaces.

But to answer your question.
Find the file

```
project/.sencha/app/sencha.cfg
```

find the line

```
app.framework=touch
```

and change it to the path (based on project) you want it to be